# Overriding print statement in java based on object class

Tags: java, oop

I have the following code in Java

I am able to print the calculated values in `printDistance` method.

Output:

4.0

3.0

But I need the output in below format(Expected Output).Please help

3D Distance = 4.0

2D Distance = 3.0

```
 public class Point2D {

    double x;
    double y;

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public Point2D(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double dist2D(Point2D p) {
        x = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(Math.pow((p.getX() - x), 2) + Math.pow((p.getY() - y), 2)));
        return x;
    }

    public static void printDistance(double d) {
        System.out.println(d);
    }

    static public void main(String args[]) {
        Point3D obj1 = new Point3D(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
        Point3D obj2 = new Point3D(3.0, 4.0,5.0);
        printDistance(obj1.dist3D(obj2));
        printDistance(obj1.dist2D(obj2));
    }
}

class Point3D extends Point2D {

    double z;

    public double getZ() {
        return z;
    }

    public Point3D(double x, double y, double z) {
        super(x, y);
        this.z = z;
    }

    public double dist3D(Point3D p) {
        return (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(Math.pow((p.getX() - x), 2) + Math.pow((p.getY() - y), 2) + +Math.pow((p.getZ() - z), 2)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just write `System.out.println("3D Distance = " + d);`?

Comment: Call `println` with the object itself instead of a `double`, and override the `toString` method in each of your classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
public class Point2D {

    double x;
    double y;

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public Point2D(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public String dist2D(Point2D p) {
        x = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(Math.pow((p.getX() - x), 2) + Math.pow((p.getY() - y), 2)));
        return "2D Distance = "+x;
    }

    public static void printDistance(String d) {
        System.out.println(d);
    }

    static public void main(String args[]) {
        Point3D obj1 = new Point3D(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
        Point3D obj2 = new Point3D(3.0, 4.0,5.0);
        printDistance(obj1.dist3D(obj2));
        printDistance(obj1.dist2D(obj2));
    }
}

class Point3D extends Point2D {

    double z;

    public double getZ() {
        return z;
    }

    public Point3D(double x, double y, double z) {
        super(x, y);
        this.z = z;
    }

    public String dist3D(Point3D p) {
        return  "3D Distance = "+ Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(Math.pow((p.getX() - x), 2) + Math.pow((p.getY() - y), 2) + +Math.pow((p.getZ() - z), 2)));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
3D Distance = 4.0
2D Distance = 3.0
```